# Solving Linear Equation Using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-equation

I am trying to solve linear equations **3x+6y+7z = 10**, **2x+y+8y = 11** & **x+3y+7z = 22** using Python and NumPy library.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[3, 6, 7],
              [2, 1, 8],
              [1, 3, 7]])
b = np.array([[10, 11, 22]])
np.linalg.solve(a, b)
```

but can't figure out what am I doing wrong in the above code which is causing to throw out the following error

> ValueError: solve: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (m,m),(m,n)->(m,n) (size 1 is different from 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `b` is a 1×3 array, so the dimensions of `a` and `b` do not match. Try

1. `b = np.array([[10], [11], [12]])` so that `b` is a 3×1 array, or
2. `b = np.array([10, 11, 12])` so that `b` is a vector with length 3 (which, as well as just `b = [10, 11, 12]`, is also admissible by `.solve()`; see [the doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html)).

The former will result in a 3×1 array as the solution, whereas the latter will result in a vector of length 3. Probably it is better to use the latter; usually we don't really care whether a vector is a column vector or a row vector. NumPy usually handles vectors in reasonable ways.